# Postgres - Query to select fields from multiple tables as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the following tables

Table 1 : Product

```
id  name  
1   Bread  
2   Bun  
3   Cake
```

Table 2: Expense Items

```
product| quantity  
1 |      100  
2 |      150  
3 |      180  
1 |      25  
2 |      30
```

Table 3: Income Items

```
product| quantity  
1 |      100  
2 |      150  
3 |      180  
1 |      25  
2 |      30
```

Now I want the results like this

```
product   |  sum of quantity of expenseitem | sum of quantity of income item  
1         |  125 |  125  
2         |  180 |  180  
3         |  180 |  180
```

What is the query to get this result ?
Thanks

Comment: With similar structures like these two, there is room to normalize by combining into one *Items* table with an indicator column for *expenses*  and *income*.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `UNION ALL` in a subquery with the condition in the aggregate function

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
    id int,
    name varchar(50)
);


INSERT INTO Product VALUES (1,'Bread');  
INSERT INTO Product VALUES (2,'Bun');  
INSERT INTO Product VALUES (3,'Cake');  

CREATE TABLE ExpenseItems(
    product int,
    quantity int
);


INSERT INTO ExpenseItems VALUES (1,100);  
INSERT INTO ExpenseItems VALUES (2,150);  
INSERT INTO ExpenseItems VALUES (3,180);  
INSERT INTO ExpenseItems VALUES (1,25);  
INSERT INTO ExpenseItems VALUES (2,30);  


CREATE TABLE IncomeItems(
    product int,
    quantity int
);


INSERT INTO IncomeItems VALUES (1,100);  
INSERT INTO IncomeItems VALUES (2,150);  
INSERT INTO IncomeItems VALUES (3,180);  
INSERT INTO IncomeItems VALUES (1,25);  
INSERT INTO IncomeItems VALUES (2,30);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT p.id,
      SUM(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN quantity END) SUMExpenseItems,
      SUM(CASE WHEN grp = 2 THEN quantity END) SUMIncomeItems
FROM (
    SELECT product, quantity,1 grp 
    FROM ExpenseItems
    UNION ALL
    SELECT product, quantity,2 
    FROM IncomeItems
) t1 JOIN Product p on p.id = t1.product
GROUP BY p.id;

| id  | sumexpenseitems | sumincomeitems |
| --- | --------------- | -------------- |
| 1   | 125             | 125            |
| 2   | 180             | 180            |
| 3   | 180             | 180            |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6cVe5KkUJgKxBhHBngd9Tj/0)

Comment: Upvoted for including the SQL to create the test data.

Comment: Do mention you are running conditional aggregation in addition to `UNION`.

Comment: @holdenweb. To be fair, the OP should have set up this reproducible example even with an SQLFiddle or Rextester. Too often answerers do more work than posters.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @D-Shih's answer, PostgreSQL 9.4+ supports the [`FILTER()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-expressions.html) clause for conditional aggregation in place of `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT p.id,
       SUM(quantity) FILTER (WHERE grp = 1) SUMExpenseItems,
       SUM(quantity) FILTER (WHERE grp = 2) SUMIncomeItems
FROM 
     -- ...same union all query...
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Depends what version. At work we still use 9.3 so have to use CASE instead.